# reading a text file into a list or array and then being able to search it in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is what I'm trying in my java program for a class I'm taking.

I have a text file that contains names, phone numbers, and email addresses of my friends. I'm supposed to build a class that will take the text file and store the information about my friends, and then will ask for a friend's name. With that name, it will display the phone number and email address for that friend. How can I do this? 
Also I have to make another class that will allow to add a friend to the list later.

I know that the use of a list is necessary.

Just not sure, how to make Java

- read the file
- split it into "categories" of name, phone, etc.,
- then be able to search for a name and return the proper information.

The text file is structured like this:

```
Name
Phone
Email
Name
..etc
```

Please help me with links/samplecode....

Comment: If you try searching for "Read file into List" and "Convert List to Object" you are likely to get hundreds of hits here on SO. Please do a little research.

Comment: I've tried a lot of different things that our textbook was using.. I've been working on this so long that I think I've confused myself past the point of return! ugh!

Answer (score 1):

Start with pojo.

```
public class Friend {
 private String name;
 private String phoneNo;
 private String email;

 /* getters & setters ommited */
}
```

Then the following will product a list of as List for your file.

```
BufferedReader in = null;
FileReader fr = null;
List<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    fr = new FileReader("yourfile.txt");
    in = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(str);


        //If 3 rows then thats our data for this Friend
        if(list.size() == 3) {
           Friend f = new Friend();
           f.setName(list.get(0));
           f.setPhoneNo(list.get(1));
           f.setEmail(list.get(2));

           friends.add(f);
           list.removeAll();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    in.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

Comment: My text file is literally just a .txt file from Notepad

Comment: Thank you! I got that set up. So how would you go about being able to imput a name and having it bring up the proper number and email?

Comment: @mcarte now that you have your data loaded you could create a method to loop through your list and return the one where the name `equals` the search term.. (if it helps click the ^ arrow :D)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep working on it. It doesn't want to work now but I will keep plugging away at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Json.

Check this link and you will see how simple it is to reading from a json-file:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/

If you checked this, you have to create a Class for your Friends:

```
  public class Friend {

        String name;
        String surname;
        String phone;

         public Friend(String name, String surname, String phone){
              this.name = name;
              this.surname = surname;
              this.phone = phone;
         }


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }
        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }
        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }


    }

In the class where you parsing the file you can do it like this:

ArrayList<Fried> friends = new ArrayList<Friends>();

// her json parsing


Friend fr = new Friend("Name you parst from Json", .... , ....);
friends.add(fr);
```

Do that in a loop and you get a ArrayList with the content in json-file

Answer (score 0):

follow the tutorial at

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml

then depending on the structure of the file split the line you get into name/phone.
then generate a new Friend object with the information and store it in your list

edit: could you post the structure of your file?

Comment: I edited my original question with the structure of the text file. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the use of a list is necessary. 
>   Just not sure how to make Java read the file

Refer to [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for info on file IO.

You can use line reader to [read each line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) from the file, and Use regex or split it by comma to get name, phone etc.

Rest all is simple algo

1. Read File
2. Iterate over each line of the file
3. Split the line values for phone etc.